# The use of reflexive pronoun myself for emphasis

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to use in the following sentences the reflexive pronoun "myself"?

> 1. I'm an interpreter myself
> 2. I'm mysеlf аn intеrрrеtеr.

Which of these two sentences are grammatically correct? Are they both correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you e.g. reacted to someone telling you, he/she is an interpreter, the correct sentence(s) would be

- I am an interpreter myself.
- I myself am an interpreter.

See [this source](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/emphatic_pronouns.htm) or googling other sources on the internet.

Comment: I know perfectly that use of emphatic pronouns. What I wanted to know is whether reflexive pronouns can be used with auxiliary verb to be. It would be great if you provide me  with the link to some grammar book. I consulted Thomson A, Martinet A, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why should you not be able to use it with a form of _to be_? I can't find a source focusing on _to be_ especially but I couldn't think of why it should be treated differently. You can see it works when looking at the examples you provided.

Comment: Your second example is little bit difficult to pronounce. And I doubt whether it is correct to use "to be" after pronoun as in your example.

Comment: Well, then we have to wait for someone confirming my sentence. I can tell you, word order in the seconds sentence is correct, whether it is hard to pronounce or not. [Googling](https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22i+myself+am%22) shows that this expression is in fact used.

Answer (score 1):

'Myself' is an apposition of 'I'.  Since it is adverbial, it could be set off with comma[s].  It works after the complement because the verb is copular (a form of 'to be').  'I am, myself, an interpreter' is grammatical, but "I'm myself" is not.  When using a pronoun, it should not be preceded by a contraction.  (Perhaps this is because the brain has extra work to unpack the contraction and find the pronoun antecedent, and the two jobs close together would be a burden.)

Comment: Adverbial? What is adverbial? I don't guite quite understand you.

Comment: An adverbial [thing] is a relation whose topic is a verb.  Any adverb is adverbial, but phrases can also be adverbial.  The 'opposite' of 'adverbial' is 'adjectival'.  (Any adjective is adjectival, but phrases can also be adjectival.)  Adverbials give additional information about an event, while adjectivals give restricting information to isolate a particular noun.

Comment: I know what  abverbial is. But can a pronoun be an adverb?

Comment: Nouns and pronouns are not adverbs, but they can be part of adverbial phrases.  Typical examples are '[on] Monday' or '[by] myself'.  The preposition is often elided.